Partition function of a rigid sphere gas with mean field aproximation
I have a gas with $N>>1$ identical particles in V and and by applying the mean-field approximation we can obtain the hamiltonian for a single particle :
$$ h_s(r,p)= \frac{|p^2|}{2m}+U_s(r) $$ with $ U_s(r)=\sum^{N-1}_{i=1}W(|r-r_i|)$
and $W(r)$ is $\infty$ if $r<a$; $W(r)$ is $\epsilon$ if $a<r<r_C$; $W(r)$ is 0 elsewhere.
I got that the partition function for a single particle:
$$Z_{1,V}(\beta)=\frac{1}{\lambda (\beta)^3}\int_V exp(-\beta \sum^{N-1}_1 W(|r-r_i|)) d^3 r  $$
so
$$\frac{1}{\lambda (\beta)^3}(\int_{V1} 0 d^3r+\int_{V2}d^3r \prod_{1}^{N-1}exp(-\beta \epsilon)+\int_{V3}exp(0)d^3r)$$
Where I divided the volume integral in the three zones of $W(r)$, for the second integral if we take $N-1\approx N$ and the $exp(-\beta \epsilon)\approx ( 1-\beta \epsilon)$ because $\beta \epsilon <<1$. And $V_3=V-V_1-V_2$
$$Z_{1,V}(\beta)=\frac{1}{\lambda (\beta)^3}(N(1-\beta \epsilon)V_2+V-V_1-V_2)$$
The problem is that I know that the result is :
$$Z_{1,V}(\beta)=\frac{1}{\lambda (\beta)^3}(V-NV_1-NV_2\beta \epsilon)$$
So may the error be that $V_3=V-NV_1-NV_2$ but I dont know why, it has sense in terms that there is N particles with volume $V_1$ and N regions with volume $V_2$ because there are N particles. But it does not seem ok to me in terms that we are using a mean field aproximation and calculate the hamiltonian for one particle... And if there are $NV_2$ volumes the integral of $V_1$ and $V_2$ must be done N times, isnt it?

What's your definition of $V_1$ and $V_2$?
